# How do I get this Newletter Form to work?

Tags: forms, submit, form-submit, newsletter

I'm not sure what to put in for href:\  Should I reference a mailhandler.php or use a mailto: command?  Or is there something better?

```
<h3 class="margin-bot">Newsletter!</h3>
                                    <form id="subscribe-form" name="sibscribe" method="post">
                                        <label><input class="subscribetext" type="text" onFocus="if(this.value =='Enter E-mail:' ) this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter E-mail:'" value="Enter E-mail:" name="keyword" /></label>
                                        <a onClick="document.getElementById('subscribe-form').submit()" class="button" href="#">subscribe</a>
                                    </form>
```

Comment: You submit your form so you don't need to put anything in href.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is meant for the site to which you get after pressing the subscribe button. Preferably the page the form was implemented in (for example to return to the index.html).

You can try it by testing it here on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net). Just put an URL in the field where now is the # and after pressing subscribe you will see that you'll be redirected to that page.